# How to get Franz messaging app start minimized and with window along the right edge of the screen?

Tags: window-manager, instant-messaging, whatsapp, franz

[Franz](https://meetfranz.com/) is probably the best in its class, but it has one UI flaw (starts in a small window somewhere in the middle of the screen and there's no setting to **start minimized**).

It might be a good idea to share custom solutions here - until the developers add this feature.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** A simple wrapper bash script that can be used as a startup app instead of Franz - e.g. *~/.bin/Login-Franz*

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start Franz
"/opt/Franz/franz" &
sleep 3
# Get the WIDTH of screen
SWIDTH="$(xrandr | grep " connected" | grep "[0-9]x[0-9]"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | cut -d '+' -f 1 | cut -d 'x' -f 1)"
# Get the HEIGHT of screen
SHEIGHT="$(xrandr | grep " connected" | grep "[0-9]x[0-9]"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | cut -d '+' -f 1 | cut -d 'x' -f 2)"
# Get the WINDOW ID of Franz
FWINDOW="$(wmctrl -l | grep " Franz$" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
# Calculate the window LEFT position for 750px width
FLEFT="$(echo $(( $SWIDTH-750 )))"
# Calculate the window HEIGHT below a 22px top panel
FHEIGHT="$(echo $(( $SHEIGHT-22 )))"
# Move and resize Franz window as above
wmctrl -i -r $FWINDOW -e 0,$FLEFT,22,750,$FHEIGHT
# Close Franz window to system tray
wmctrl -ic $FWINDOW
exit 0
```

**Note:** Some adjustment might be required for other desktop configurations than the one with a 22px top panel and nothing else on the right edge.

**2)** A custom .desktop file: *~/.config/autostart/franz-startup.desktop*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Franz
Comment=Franz Startup Script
Exec="~/.bin/Login-Franz"
Icon=franz
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=10
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

**Note:** You might need to change "**~/**" to "**/home/YourUserName/**" in the executable path.